# UnidentifiedImageError Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, converters, pdf2image

I try to convert a PDF file into images, using Pdf2Image but I get the following error message:

**UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f241957a950>**

When I worked yesterday on the same notebook and the same code, everything worked just fine.
I already looked up similar questions, but no solution seemed to fix my problem.
Does anybody have an answer to this?
Here is the code:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes
file = "/content/example.pdf"
images = convert_from_bytes(open(file, 'rb').read(), size=800, dpi=800)
```

I already tried to `!sudo apt-get update`, or to work with `convert_from_path`
poppler is also installed via `!apt-get install poppler-utils`

If it helps, [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10w7dOxP0NHOj4VU-CU3jhoLTCwZTxrCG?usp=sharing) is the full notebook I am working on.

I already discovered, that if I only run `!sudo apt-get update`, `!apt-get install poppler-utils` and `!pip install pdf2image` the code will run perfectly. It might have something to do with installing the other tools like tesseract, PyPdf2, ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was pillow.

Tesseract is working on pillow v. 9.2.0, while pdf2image is only working on pillow v. 7.2.0.

After adding `!pip install -I pillow==7.2.0` after all the pip installations, everything seems to work out fine.

Maybe this is not the best solution but it works for me right now, maybe someone knows a better solution.